# Include email header in app engine using go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The google app engine documentation doesn't describe how to include an email header, how do you do it, i.e. How do you change this?

```
    msg := &mail.Message{
            Sender:  "Example.com Support <support@example.com>",
            To:      []string{"email@bob.com"},
            Subject: "Confirm your registration",
            Body:    fmt.Sprintf(confirmMessage, url),
    }
    if err := mail.Send(c, msg); err != nil {
            c.Errorf("Couldn't send email: %v", err)
    }
```

Comment: what kind of email header are you trying to send ? If is esthetic html then should go inside the .Body string

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise some people don't know what an email header is, [Wikipedia has a good definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Header_fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **[`appengine/mail` reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/mail/reference)** you can find that *type  Message* has a field called `Headers`:

```
// Extra mail headers.
// See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/mail/overview
// for permissible headers.
Headers mail.Header
```

The type `mail.Header` can be found in the **[`net/mail`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/#Header)** package, and only the following header names may be used, as described in the [above overview link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/mail/#Go_Sending_mail_with_headers):

- In-Reply-To
- List-Id
- List-Unsubscribe
- On-Behalf-Of
- References
- Resent-Date
- Resent-From
- Resent-To

**Example:** (untested)

```
import netmail "net/mail" // mail is already taken by appengine/mail
```

...

```
msg := &mail.Message{
        Sender:  "Example.com Support <support@example.com>",
        To:      []string{"email@bob.com"},
        Subject: "Confirm your registration",
        Body:    fmt.Sprintf(confirmMessage, url),
        Headers:  netmail.Header{"In-Reply-To": []string{"123456789"}},
}
```